# gdb golang, how do you print the base class info?

Tags: go, gdb

When I debug protoc-gen-go, I want to print **generator.FileDescriptor**'s base class infomation, its base class is **github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/descriptor.FileDescriptorProto**.

gdb print type:

```
ptype file
```

gdb outputs:

```
type = struct generator.FileDescriptor {
struct github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/descriptor.FileDescriptorProto **github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/descriptor.FileDescriptorProto;
struct []*generator.Descriptor desc;
struct []*generator.EnumDescriptor enum;
struct []*generator.ExtensionDescriptor ext;
struct []*generator.ImportedDescriptor imp;
map[string]*github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/descriptor.SourceCodeInfo_Location comments;
map[generator.Object][]generator.symbol exported;
int index;
bool proto3;
```

} *

now I want to print the baseclass **descriptor.FileDescriptorProto** info, how to do that? I am a beginner in golang programming. I tried following manners, but neither workerd.

```
ptype file.github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/descriptor.FileDescriptorProto
ptype file.*github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go/descriptor.FileDescriptorProto
ptype file.FileDescriptorProto
ptype file.*FileDescriptorProto
...
```

how do you print the base class info of **file *FileDescriptor**, this class is defined in **package generator**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it you're looking for? Go doesn't have classes or inheritance.

Comment: I think OP is trying to display the full type declaration of an anonymous field.

Comment: @JimB I want to display the fields' info - desciptor.FileDescriptorProto, it is included within file. I search golang specification, this manner can be treated as 'Is-A' inheritance, but I don't know how to print its fields' value.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, I want to print the anonymous field value.

Comment: @zhangjie: while it's not relevant to this particular question, it still is _not_ inheritance, and is definitely does _not_ create an "Is-A" relationship. This is just composition ("Has-A") and delegation, and a type can satisfy an interface, which only checks if that type "has a" method set that matches.